# Play spotify through Skype?

Tags: audio, skype, spotify

So I tried this solution by an user [Play music in a Skype call](https://superuser.com/questions/375181/play-music-in-a-skype-call)

I followed the steps but when I asked my friend if he heard any music, he told me that there was a weird loud noise, but he could hear my voice, no music.
I can't wrap my head around how VAC works. Does somebody know how to make it work with Spotify (even if it repeats my friend's voice)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To Play music in Skype Call, simply use Voicemeeter Virtual Mixer. Download and user manual (see case study #1) on www.voicemeeter.com

Comment: I looked at this but didnt know that they had a manual on such specific cases.
I'll take a look and report back.