# Skype, windows 10, recorded videos, speakers

Tags: amplification, speakers, audio

I'm using the above and those who listen in on Skype are having problems hearing certain recorded videos.

They can hear everything said on microphones at our location but when a video or music on the computer are played they lose sound. Sometimes they can hear white noise, sometimes a broken transmission but the majority of the time they hear nothing.

Any suggestions? Any experiences? Is it skype, the computer, the amplifier, the speakers, the microphone, the sound card???

We've changed cables but no help.

Thanks in advance

Comment: this is a site about electronics design and engineering. Not about any problem in the general vicinity of eletronics

Comment: Mixer settings? Check all Skype settings which MAY have source related settings. Or not.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Play music in a Skype call](https://superuser.com/questions/375181/play-music-in-a-skype-call/1250642#1250642)

Comment: You can find helpful answers to variations of this question by searching here for "skype stereo mix". The best one is probably: https://superuser.com/questions/375181/play-music-in-a-skype-call I recommend using https://www.vb-audio.com/Voicemeeter as it allows you to control the volume of your voice independently of your video/music source.

Comment: Do you actually try to record something "playing in the room" or are you presenting said media within the session?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "...when a video or music on the computer are played they lose sound"? Do you mean they just can't hear the video you're trying to present but they continue to be able to hear the microphone input once the video starts playing... or that they suddenly lose the audio from the microphone *as well* as not being able to hear the video?