# Can't get Stereo Mix to work through Skype no matter what

Tags: windows-10, audio, skype, microphone, stereo

I'm trying to get **Stereo Mix** to work through **Skype** and I've been trouble shooting for ages. I've tried every fix from the first 2 pages of google and my friend who has gotten **Stereo Mix** to work himself told me all the exact settings he was using, to no avail.

When I change the **Skype** setting of my microphone to **Stereo Mix** I can still hear people in the call, but they can no longer hear me, nor sound coming from my computer - and my computer still shows in the recording tab that my microphone sound is working.

I have tried every variation of the listen settings and downloaded and updated the **Stereo Mix** drivers from Realtek (Though my friend says mine looks different from his - I'm on Windows 10 he's on 7 though). Nothing works. I tried unplugging my headphones, making **Stereo Mix** default communication, and making it the full Default Device. I swear I've tried everything...

**What else can I try to get Stereo Mix to work for sharing audio in Skype?**

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issues with Stereo Mix - there is something about it that just doesn't work on my PC, whether due to some Windows 10 issue or what, I don't know.  I recommend dropping trying to use it, and get [VoiceMeeter](http://www.vb-audio.com/Voicemeeter/index.htm) from VB-Audio.  It is free to download (but donateware).  I was in exactly your situation and this solution worked for me, where I just wanted to play some videos over a Skype meeting and have the other party hear the audio.

VoiceMeeter is an audio mixing app that can mix up to 3 sources out to 2 different outputs (1 local, including up to 2 devices, and 1 output source that can be used as a microphone to drive Skype or another streaming or recording app).  It installs one set of in and out virtual audio devices, and you can get a second one, VB-Cable, from the same place.

They have more advance options as well, including a "banana" version of VoiceMeeter and 2 more virtual audio cables, that require some kind of donation to get, but then you can mix 5 input sources out to 5 separate outputs (usually don't need this unless you want to record multi-track files for post-editing).

There is a [full user manual](http://www.vb-audio.com/Voicemeeter/Voicemeeter_UserManual.pdf) on the site.  I give some more details in my [answer here](https://superuser.com/a/1250173/744680).